# Check the "destroyer" of a component/directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following scenario: a Directive detects changes that happen to an ElementRef, and performs actions when it is destroyed:

Template:

```
<input doSomethingOnDestory *ngIf="showMyInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myInput">
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
selector: '[ngModel][doSomethingOnDestory]'
})
export class DoSomethingOnDestory Directive implements OnDestroy {
    @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){}

    ngOnDestroy() {
        //Do something to the model
    }
}
```

Now I've come to a scenario in which I want to run `//Do something to the model` only if the component is destroyed **by itself** (for example, by `showMyInput` becoming falsy) and not by an "outside destroyer" (the whole wrapping component of the form being destroyed, for example)

How can I do that?

Thanks :-)